# macOS & dyld: Symbol not found: _usdt_create_provider

Tags: node.js, macos, macos-mojave, dtrace

In short, I'm unable to install @pact-foundation/pact-node on my development computer and from what I gather it seems to be loosely related to being on macOS 10.14. When I say loosely, this does not affect my other non-development computer running the same stack.

Within nvm I've tried using Node 8.14.0, 8.15.0, 9.4.0, 10.14.2, 10.15.0 and 11.6.0, in addition to system Node, which is also 11.6.0. Each version results in the same error messages, regardless of whether I'm in my team's project directory or in an otherwise empty sandbox directory.

Until a few minutes ago I was running macOS 10.14.1 and am seeing the same problems on 10.14.2. There are no updates that haven't been installed.

The package installation output is as follows.

```
$ npm install @pact-foundation/pact-node

> dtrace-provider@0.8.7 install /Users/andrewgould/www/sandbox/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js

  ACTION binding_gyp_ndtp_target_build_ndtp .
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/ndtp.stamp

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /Users/andrewgould/www/sandbox/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall


> caporal@0.10.0 postinstall /Users/andrewgould/www/sandbox/node_modules/caporal
> (test -f ./node_modules/husky/bin/install.js && node ./node_modules/husky/bin/install.js) || exit 0


> @pact-foundation/pact-node@6.20.0 postinstall /Users/andrewgould/www/sandbox/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-node
> node postinstall.js

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _usdt_create_provider
  Referenced from: /Users/andrewgould/www/sandbox/node_modules/dtrace-provider/src/build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _usdt_create_provider
  Referenced from: /Users/andrewgould/www/sandbox/node_modules/dtrace-provider/src/build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

Abort trap: 6
```

Has anyone seen errors like these before? Is there a solution known?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this issue was caused by `binutils`, which I had installed via Homebrew. Uninstalling that fixed the problem.

From the [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) website, the main packages included in it are `ld`, the GNU linker, and `as`, the GNU assembler. Both tools are included with macOS, however the Homebrew versions of these tools caused the conflicts shown in the above question.